# jquery running same function on multiple elements relatives to 'This'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$(".column a").mouseenter(function() {
var color_column=$(this).closest('.column').children('.coloured-strip').css('color');

$(this).siblings('p').animate({color:color_column},2000);
$(this).animate({color:color_column},2000);
});
```

There's any way I can group the two animate functions into one since they're identical?

thanks
luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$(this).siblings('p').add(this).animate({color:color_column},2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) method:

```
$(this).siblings('p').andSelf().animate({color:color_column},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$(this).siblings('p').animate({color:color_column},2000);
$(this).animate({color:color_column},2000);
```

You can do:

```
$(this).siblings('p').add(this).animate({color:color_column},2000);
```

[See the documentation for `.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add).